# SQL 2012 User Permissions Possibilities

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

MS SQL 2012.  I have setup multiple schemas, one of which is `Storage`.

The database will be connected to a website, so I so not want to allow the user `MyWebUser` to have any kind of access to anything tied to this schema.  Right now, this schema only contains tables.  And the user is `db_datareader` & `db_datawriter` `public`

I have views and stored procedures setup that are tied to other Schemas, and I want the `MyWebUser` to be able to use these (CRUD operations only)

My question is (and I have to ask, because the web app part of this is not built as of yet), if I specify `Deny` the user from accessing anything to do with the schema `Storage` will that user still be able to perform the basic CRUD operations I mention above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DENY` overrides all, so you should be able to:

```
alter role db_datareader add member MyWebUser;
alter role db_datawriter add member MyWebUser;
deny select, insert, update, delete on schema::Storage to MyWebUser;
```

Comment: oh...i know that much :-)...  my question is 'will it effect the CRUD schemas?'

Comment: It will only affect CRUD on the Storage schema. And by that, I mean explicit insert, select, update, and delete statements against objects in that schema. If you're doing data mods through stored procedures, those will still work (assuming permission is granted).

Comment: perfect.   yeah all work will be done thru procs  ..   even selects will be done through procs...   sweet....    thanks